# More idiomatic date conversion in Spark DataFrame to ISO 8601 date

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, date-conversion, idioms

I am using Spark 2.4.5 with Scala 2.12.11 and I have a column `registered` which is string with dates following these examples,

```
Mar 23, 2005
Dec 6, 2005
```

I am converting this column to DateType with this code which appears to be functionally correct. The steps are,

- Convert string "Dec 6, 2005" to "2005-12-06"
- Use `cast(DateType)` to convert ISO 8601 date to date type.

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

  object Utils {
    private val dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy")

    def convertToIso(date: String): Option[String] = {
      Option(date).map {
        nnDate =>
          val dt = dtFormatter.parse(nnDate)
          DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(dt)
      }
    }

    def toIsoUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf(convertToIso _)
  }

  private def structureProfiles(profileDf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    profileDf
      .withColumn(
        "registered_dt",
        Utils.toIsoUdf(col("registered")).cast(DateType))
  }
  ```

The column may be null hence the use of `Option` which seems to work fine.

Is there a more idiomatic approach?

**Update**

I found this much simpler approach. `Utils` is not required.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date

df1
  .withColumn(
    "registered", to_date(col("registered"), "MMM d, yyy"))
```

Comment: Pass only not null ```registered ``` values to UDF

Comment: @Srinivas - Intriguing, why? Passing null works okay.

Comment: updated one will it work with null values in registered column ??

Comment: I am just thinking instead of passing all values to UDF, pass only not null values .. as UDF is black box..

Comment: `to_date` is more effective than UDF from performance point of view